# Code sign validation failing during xcodebuild and Failed to read entitlements for xcrun

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcrun

I have tried every available solution over here and on the internet.

I am trying to automate the iOS build process, and the clean, build and archive process succeed with these 5 warnings (errors) failing code sign validation.

```
warning: The CodeResources file is missing and it must be a symbolic link to      _CodeSignature/CodeResources.  Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume (not a remote SMB volume), and be certain to use the Mac OS X Finder to compress it (-19062)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.      At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper:  (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  Your MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2, so you must define CFBundleIconFile or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57. (-19013)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

If i try to ignore the warning or use the debug config to skip validating the codesign,  xcrun to package the .app to .ipa fails with following error

```
env SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication -v 
/Users/XXXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_11_31_23.app -o 
/Users/XXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_11_31_23.ipa 
--sign iPhone\ Distribution 
--embed/Users/XXXXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/cms_local_repo/6072/76/XXXXXXXX_AppStore_11_07_1373971044.mobileprovision

error: Failed to read entitlements from '/var/folders/n6/8tsx1pss5v3fq3sfpz8379r0ms3b7m/T/Rm5MudWNER/Payload/Test_22_07_13_11_31_23.app'
```

My xcodebuild command is following as I am working with workspaces

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -verbose 
-workspace /Users/XXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/git_local_repo/11330/80/PDFReader.git/XXXXXX.xcworkspace 
-scheme _DEFAULT -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution:" 
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=73DE6F20-FAB9-46A2-9825-35D7DE82CD4D 
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/ahsandar/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_13_26_29.app
OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /tmp/xcoder1374496105" clean
```

My xcrun command looks like this

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -log -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v 
"/Users/XXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_13_26_29.app" -o 
"/Users/XXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_13_26_29.ipa" --sign "iPhone Distribution:" 
--embed "/Users/XXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/cms_local_repo/11330/80/XXXXXX_AppStore_11_07_1373
```

I am using xcoder gem to create temporary keychain to add my p12 in it. all verification on the archive are successful using the command line tools for codesign.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have set minimus os smaller than possible in project settings, possible your icons have wrong size. Please read again your first log.

And be sure that you provide correct params to xcodebuild command.
For me clean works good with these args:

```
xcodebuild clean -sdk iphoneos5.1 -project '${PBXPROJ}.xcodeproj' -configuration '${MCONFIG}' -alltargets DSTROOT="${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${kPROVISONING_PROFILE}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${DEVELOPER_NAME}"
```

And build works good like that:

```
xcodebuild install -sdk iphoneos5.1 -project "${PBXPROJ}.xcodeproj" -configuration "${MCONFIG}" -target "${TARGET}" DSTROOT="${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${kPROVISONING_PROFILE}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${DEVELOPER_NAME}"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am working with workspaces so my xcodebuild command looks like this, 


`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -verbose` 
`-workspace /Users/XXXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/git_local_repo/9915/79/XXXXXXX.git/XXXXXX.xcworkspace `
`-scheme _DEFAULT -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution:" `
`PROVISIONING_PROFILE=73DE6F20-FAB9-46A2-9825-35D7DE82CD4D `
`CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/XXXXXXX/source/digital_hub/cms/final/cms_repo/H1/45/ZD/0v/U9/Rr/gT/builds/Test_22_07_13_13_09_37.app `
`OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /tmp/xcoder1374495095" clean`

Comment: I see you try to use different keychain than default - I'm strongly recommended do it with minimum settings (default keychain, default provisioning (from xcodeproj), etc). When you have result - then you can try put more params. By the way Ive used (cd ${FOLDER}; xcodebuild ....) it looks better than long ways. Thx,

Comment: solved these issues , the target provided to me was missing settings and path to my .app folder was wrong hence the code sign failed, xcodebuild fails to link the CodeResource folder so had to do it explicitly. thanks for responding to my question.